# getting desktop-columns-3 tablet-columns-2 mobile-columns-1 on my website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

Recently I was performing changes with my wordpress website. I am getting `desktop-columns-3 tablet-columns-2 mobile-columns-1` on my every product page.

I am clueless since when I search for this error it is only telling me about the sizing not any reason why I am getting this written everywhere.

[image]

Getting issue with all product pages

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too and this is how I fixed it.

Go to wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wp-template-functions.php

Line 708 has the line:

$loop_start = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', ob_get_clean() );

That line is already defined in several places, so i've commented it out and it's resolved the problem. I don't know if it's broken something somewhere else but everything seems to be working fine for now.. If it does break something my next idea is make it "echo false" or something.

Either way, this seems to work for now. Good luck with your site!

Answer (score 1):

At your theme find a file function.php
add new function like this :

```
    <?php
// add any new or customised functions here

function woocommerce_product_loop_start() {
    ob_start();

    wc_set_loop_prop( 'loop', 0 );

    wc_get_template( 'loop/loop-start.php' );

    $loop_start = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'ob_get_clean()' );

    return $loop_start;
}
```

it will replace the original function from plugin. Hope it will be save your problem

Answer (score -1):

Look for Function woocommerce_product_loop_start in the wp-content / plugins / woocommerce / includes / wp-template-functions.php file and replace it with the following code:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start' ) ) {
    /**
     * Output the start of a product loop. By default this is a UL
     *
     * @access public
     * @param bool $echo
     * @return string
     */
    function woocommerce_product_loop_start( $echo = true ) {
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'loop/loop-start.php' );
        if ( $echo )
            echo ob_get_clean();
        else
            return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```